# TwinCAT 3 Ads function InvokeRpcMethod() doesn't work and give an error of "Value is null" for symbol

Tags: plc, twincat

I want to call/invoke a PLC method from ADS.

Based off the example described in the function definition (TcAdsClient.InvokeRpcMethod) here [https://infosys.beckhoff.com/index.php?content=../content/1031/tcadsnetref/6358337803.html&id=]

I tried making similar function on the PLC side and tried invoking on the ADS side didn't work and gives me an error "Value cannot be null" for symbol.

Following is how call the method.

```
short result = (short)client.InvokeRpcMethod("MAIN", "M_Add", new object[] {(short)1, (short)4});
```

Yes PLC is running and client is connected I am able to access other PLC variables. All I am trying is to follow the sample code provided in the link above. Following is the exception I get on the call of "InvokeRpcMethod()"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you explain better from what do you get that value cannot be null error? Are you sure the client is connected etc?

Comment: I modified my question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do ADS Remote Procedure Call, you need to invoke a Function Block method and not a Program method.

So just create a Function Block, let's say FB_AdsManager and declare it in MAIN like this:

```
fbAdsManager    : FB_AdsManager;
```

FB_AdsManager has a method adsRemoteCall (don't forget the {attribute 'TcRpcEnable'} attribute)

Now you can call the method from your program:

```
client.InvokeRpcMethod("MAIN.fbAdsManager", "adsRemoteCall", new object[] {});
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked as you described. (*better than Beckhoff's outdated documentation)